# How to close previous EventSource

Tags: html, ecmascript-6, server-sent-events

```html
<button onclick="hoge()">hoge</button>
<script>
function hoge(){
  if(es){
    es.close()
  }
  var es = new EventSource('/hoge')
  es.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to save resources, so it clicked and start connect EventSource.
The new connection start each time clicked, so I want to disconnect the previous connection.
I tried the above code but it didn't work. How should I do please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the actual scope of the first `EventSource` when you call the function the second time, so the variable `es` is empty for you even though you have an `EventSource` already instantiated.

I am not sure why do you close and recreate the EventSource in the first place, but here is a solution for your exact problem:

Try this:

```
<script>
var eventSource;

function hoge(){
    if(eventSource){
        eventSource.close()
    }

    eventSource = new EventSource('/hoge')

    eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
</script>
```

Have in mind that the `eventSource` is located in the global scope(or in other words, it is directly attached to the window object in the context of a browser) this way, so you might want to wrap the whole code in a module or at least in another function. In short, use this:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var eventSource;

    function hoge(){
        if(eventSource){
            eventSource.close()
        }

        eventSource = new EventSource('/hoge')

        eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. it's clear!
`var eventSource = {
      close : function(){
        console.log(null)
      }
    }`
In this way, I had to prepare the object on purpose and define the function(close) in advance.
It is very troublesome, but there is nothing you can do

Comment: @nori Sorry, didn't get your point? You don't have to prepare anything. Why do you make a stub object? "eventSource.close()" won't be called unless there is an eventSource instance assigned to the variable, so you don't have to setup a mock 'close' function yourself. Ofcourse, this will work if you're not manipulating the variable yourself in another place(which obviously you shouldn't do).

Comment: oh! only declare variables!  Solved thanks to your just advice!

Comment: I always declare `var eventSource = ""` etc ever.I don't have to substitute values